# Springboot ajax xhr failed load 404 error

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I'm sending a form value to Controller to load more data from database by ajax call in Springboot project.
but getting 404 xhr failed error(I'm using Spring security also).

I've attached Controller, Script and error log

```
@GetMapping("/company_selection")
    public String showCompanies(Model model,  @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails user) {
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle","Select Company");
        model.addAttribute("companies",companyService.listCompanies(user.getId()));
        model.addAttribute("CompanySelectCriteria", new CompanySelectCriteria());
        Map<Long, String> years = new TreeMap<>();
        model.addAttribute("years", years);
        return "company_select";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/company_selection", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Map<Long, String> showYears(Model model, @RequestBody YearCriteria yearCriteria) {
        Map<Long, String> years = companyService.listYears(yearCriteria.getCompanyName());
        return years;
    }
```

JQuery Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#companies").change(function() {
      var company = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      var json = {
       "companyName" : company
      };
 
      $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       contentType : "application/json",
       url : "/company_selection",
       data : JSON.stringify(json),
       dataType : 'json',
       cache : false,
       timeout : 600000,
       success : function(data) {    
        var html = '';
        html += '<option value="0"></option>';
        for (let elem of data.entries()) {
            html += '<option value="' + '${elem[0]}' + '">'
                   + '${elem[1]}'
                   + '</option>';
        }
        html += '</option>';
        $('#year_id').html(html);
       },
       error : function(e) {
        alert(e);
       }
      });
    });
   });
  </script>
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually web applications use default context path for all controllers. It specified by property `server.servlet.context-path=path`. Check default value for it or specify your own, and use path like that: `/path/company_selection`

Comment: My app's path is default, localhost:8080 shows home page fine and other pages display correctly

Comment: Could you show annotations on your controller class?

Comment: just @Controller above class name

Comment: And there is no any proxy between browser and your spring boot app, right?

Comment: yes, there's no proxy

Comment: then just try specify url : "/<your-jar-name>/company_selection",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239596/discussion-between-nandha-and-vladimir-shadrin).